# Specify controller and model on a view that doesn't have a router

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple app that is using ember-data to load from a RESTful web service and display the data using the route to specify the model.

```
App.AreasRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Area.find();
    }
});
```

Then I can render the data in the handlebars template using {{#each content}}

But I want to have a second area of data from a different model displayed on the page as well.  I started by creating a View and then rendering the view as part of my application template using {{view App.AnotherView}} which correctly renders the view.

However, this view doesn't have a route and therefore I have nowhere to tell it where to get it's data from.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to load additional content is in the `setupController` hook of the route.

For example, if you define your route as

```
App.AreasRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Area.find();
    },
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('someArea', App.Area.find('area_id'));
    }
});
```

Then the `Area` model with id `area_id` can be accessed by `{{someArea}}` in your template.

Comment: That isn't quite what I was after but helped me solve the problem! I can already iterate the areas because ember defaults ot setting them to the controllers content property. But I can set a different variable to whatever I want using this - which works.

Comment: So, to clarify I did the following so that I can access the data from my view that is inserted into the application template (on all routes).

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('otherdata', App.AnotherModel.find());
    }
});